# Validating sameness or difference of a relationship

Tags: hypothesis-testing, function

I am measuring a response variable Y(x,t) which theoretically is a function of both time (t) and space (x). I have measurements for Y as t varies for different spatial points x. On inspecting visually Y vs t at different x's, there seems to be a clear distinction in the relationship, in other words Y vs t looks different at different x's. Is there a statistical way to prove that Y indeed is a function of x too?

Thanks.

Comment: Are there measurement errors? Do the observed time values differ for each x?

Comment: Yes there is measurement noise, and yes the observed values differ for each x.

Comment: Then you're going to need a model